# How do I parse multiple levels(arrays) within JSON file using python?

Tags: python, json

Here is the sample JSON which I am trying to parse in python. 
I am having hard time parsing through "files":
Any help appreciated.

```
{
    "startDate": "2016-02-19T08:19:30.764-0700",
    "endDate": "2016-02-19T08:20:19.058-07:00",
    "files": [
        {
            "createdOn": "2017-02-19T08:20:19.391-0700",
            "contentType": "text/plain",
            "type": "jpeg",
            "id": "Photoshop",
            "fileUri": "output.log"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "linkToken": "-3418849688029673541",
    "subscriberViewers": [
        "null"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? `files` is just a list of dictionaries; you would iterate through it like any other list (`for fileinfo in data['files']:` ...).

Comment: Please show your effort into solving this issue; it is highly unlikely that other users will help you if they see none of your attempts into solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To print the `id` of each file in the array:

```
import json

data = json.loads(rawdata)                                                      

files = data['files']                                                           

for f in files:                                                              
    print(f['id'])
```

Comment: ...although I would avoid using `file` as the name of a variable, since you've now masked the builtin `file` type.